# Pandas - Adding New Columns - Using Loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am new to python and working on a dataframe whose first column is 'Country' followed by 144 columns of numeric data.

**Goal and Expected Result:**

Need to create new columns which is an average of 3 columns. ex: first new column is an average of first 3 columns of numerical data (columns numbers 1,2 & 3). The next new column is an average of subsequent 3 columns (columns numbers 4,5 & 6) and so on. Since this dataset is having 144 columns we need to create 48 new columns (144/3). Please find the snapshot of the dataframe below

[image: Snapshot of the Data]

I am using the following code which is definitely not an ideal way of doing it and there should be a better of doing it.

Can someone suggest if the output can be achieved using a loop function?

```py
df = pd.read_excel('/content/df_Data.xlsx')

df[2010_1] = df[[1,2,3]].mean(axis=1)
df[2010_2] = df[[4,5,6]].mean(axis=1)
df[2010_3] = df[[7,8,9]].mean(axis=1)
df[2010_4] = df[[10,11,12]].mean(axis=1)
df[2011_1] = df[[13,14,15]].mean(axis=1)
df[2011_2] = df[[16,17,18]].mean(axis=1)
df[2011_3] = df[[19,20,21]].mean(axis=1)
df[2011_4] = df[[22,23,24]].mean(axis=1)
df[2012_1] = df[[25,26,27]].mean(axis=1)
df[2012_2] = df[[28,29,30]].mean(axis=1)
df[2012_3] = df[[31,32,33]].mean(axis=1)
df[2012_4] = df[[34,35,36]].mean(axis=1)
df[2013_1] = df[[37,38,39]].mean(axis=1)
df[2013_2] = df[[40,41,42]].mean(axis=1)
df[2013_3] = df[[43,44,45]].mean(axis=1)
df[2013_4] = df[[46,47,48]].mean(axis=1)
df[2014_1] = df[[49,50,51]].mean(axis=1)
df[2014_2] = df[[52,53,54]].mean(axis=1)
df[2014_3] = df[[55,56,57]].mean(axis=1)
df[2014_4] = df[[58,59,60]].mean(axis=1)
df[2015_1] = df[[61,62,63]].mean(axis=1)
df[2015_2] = df[[64,65,66]].mean(axis=1)
df[2015_3] = df[[67,68,69]].mean(axis=1)
df[2015_4] = df[[70,71,72]].mean(axis=1)
df[2016_1] = df[[73,74,75]].mean(axis=1)
df[2016_2] = df[[76,77,78]].mean(axis=1)
df[2016_3] = df[[79,80,81]].mean(axis=1)
df[2016_4] = df[[82,83,84]].mean(axis=1)
df[2017_1] = df[[85,86,87]].mean(axis=1)
df[2017_2] = df[[88,89,90]].mean(axis=1)
df[2017_3] = df[[91,92,93]].mean(axis=1)
df[2017_4] = df[[94,95,96]].mean(axis=1)
df[2018_1] = df[[97,98,99]].mean(axis=1)
df[2018_2] = df[[100,101,102]].mean(axis=1)
df[2018_3] = df[[103,104,105]].mean(axis=1)
df[2018_4] = df[[106,107,108]].mean(axis=1)
df[2019_1] = df[[109,110,111]].mean(axis=1)
df[2019_2] = df[[112,113,114]].mean(axis=1)
df[2019_3] = df[[115,116,117]].mean(axis=1)
df[2019_4] = df[[118,119,120]].mean(axis=1)
df[2020_1] = df[[121,122,123]].mean(axis=1)
df[2020_2] = df[[124,125,126]].mean(axis=1)
df[2020_3] = df[[127,128,129]].mean(axis=1)
df[2020_4] = df[[130,131,132]].mean(axis=1)
df[2021_1] = df[[133,134,135]].mean(axis=1)
df[2021_2] = df[[136,137,138]].mean(axis=1)
df[2021_3] = df[[139,140,141]].mean(axis=1)
df[2021_4] = df[[142,143,144]].mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much more verbose than the other answer but hopefully still helpful. The idea is to (1) melt the "wide table" to a "long table", (2) add a year_quarter column, and (3) group on that column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

num_cols = 14
num_rows = 5

np.random.seed(1)

#Create a table in the same shape that you describe
#columns are ints which I'm guessing represent months
df = pd.DataFrame({
    c+1:np.random.randint(1,20,num_rows) for c in range(num_cols)
})

#Melt the table to "long form" where each row has the previous column name and value
long_df = df.melt(var_name='month',value_name='val')

#Add quarter_year column
years = long_df['month'].sub(1).floordiv(12).add(2010)
quarters = long_df['month'].sub(1).mod(12).floordiv(3).add(1) #better way to do this?
long_df['year_quarter'] = years.astype(str)+'_'+quarters.astype(str)

#Use groupby to get the mean value per year_quarter (you can reshape the table later if you need)
long_df.groupby('year_quarter')['val'].mean().reset_index(name='mean_quarter_values')
```

Here is what the wide `df` table looks like

[image]

The `long_df` table

[image]

The final output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. However I believe there is some issue with the following line of code - `years = long_df['month'].floordiv(13)+2020`

Comment: I've retried it and its working for me. is it producing an error for you? or are the years incorrect? oh wait, I see, you want it to start from 2010 instead of 2020. I've edited the code

Comment: thanks, looks like I made some logic errors determining quarters and years. I think I've fixed it now

Comment: thanks, you're right! I think I fixed this in the last edit

If you try `long_df.head(40)` you'll see that for row# 32 the month is still 7 because I'm simulating 5 values for each month and in the `long_df` there will be 5 rows for each month.

If you try `long_df.tail(15)` and look at row# 60 you can see the year advancing and the quarter resetting to 1

Comment: all of these errors I made shows why it is probably better to use the `period_range` suggested by @Shubham

Comment: Yes. It is returning the desired output. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

### No loop solution

```
out = df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1]) // 3, axis=1).mean()
out.columns = pd.period_range('2010', freq='Q', periods=out.shape[1])
```

### Explained

Create a grouper for the columns axis which partitions the columns in a 48 consecutive sets. This can be achieved using the below code:

```
>>> np.arange(df.shape[1]) // 3

array([ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,
        5,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 11,
       11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16,
       17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22,
       22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 28,
       28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33,
       34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39,
       39, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45,
       45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47], dtype=int32)
```

Now group the dataframe along the columns axis using the above partitions and calculate `mean`, then generate a period range starting from `2010` having a quarterly frequency  and assign this period range to the columns of the target dataframe. The period range can be generated using the below code:

```
>>> pd.period_range('2010', freq='Q', periods=out.shape[1])

PeriodIndex(['2010Q1', '2010Q2', '2010Q3', '2010Q4', '2011Q1', '2011Q2',
             '2011Q3', '2011Q4', '2012Q1', '2012Q2', '2012Q3', '2012Q4',
             '2013Q1', '2013Q2', '2013Q3', '2013Q4', '2014Q1', '2014Q2',
             '2014Q3', '2014Q4', '2015Q1', '2015Q2', '2015Q3', '2015Q4',
             '2016Q1', '2016Q2', '2016Q3', '2016Q4', '2017Q1', '2017Q2',
             '2017Q3', '2017Q4', '2018Q1', '2018Q2', '2018Q3', '2018Q4',
             '2019Q1', '2019Q2', '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1', '2020Q2',
             '2020Q3', '2020Q4', '2021Q1', '2021Q2', '2021Q3', '2021Q4'],
            dtype='period[Q-DEC]')
```

Comment: Note: If the `Country` column is not already set as index, then you have to first set it as an index of dataframe before using the above solution.